# Is there a dictionary for math notation?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

As a non-mathematician who loves the elegance of mathematics, I'm often confused about certain syntax I see. For example, $2+2$ is "2 plus 2" obviously. But things get more complicated when, for example, set notation is used. When jumping into a subject that uses complicated notation, it is hard to understand what is being said and very hard to find out what the notation is called.

Is there a resource that can help?

Comment: The beginning or end of any textbook will generally define important non-standard symbols used.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols) has a list, but due to the large number of topics in mathematics, it is hardly extensive.  If encountering a symbol not on that list, try searching materials more closely related to the context in which you encountered it, or try finding what the TeX command is for the symbol on [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) to try to gather context or focus your search based on its name.

Comment: [Perhaps useful (pdf), Handbook for Spoken Mathematics](http://web.efzg.hr/dok/MAT/vkojic/Larrys_speakeasy.pdf)

Comment: It is perhaps worth mentioning that some symbols represent different things depending on context.

Comment: Also of interest, [comprehensive LaTeX symbol list](http://get-software.net/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Comment: @JMoravitz, My page was not refreshed for some time then...Thx.